# For numbers $x,y \in \Bbb N$ where x is not a power of y or vice versa, are there numbers $a,b \in \Bbb N$ where $x^a$ = $y^b$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, exponentiation, natural-numbers

My original problem was I wanted to find numbers where $13^a = 2^b$ but I realized this had a broader problem to it.

So the pretty obvious thing to first point out is that an even number to any power will still be even and an odd number to any power will still be odd. So if x or y is even and the other is odd then a and b are impossible. Disproving my idea above.

I assume the answer is that a and b are impossible for all x and y's but I'm having trouble putting it into a working proof and my mathematical vocab is not that strong. I'm also almost positive it has something to do with factorization ie. $x^4 = y^4 * z^4$ where $x=y*z$ and that all numbers can be broken up into prime factors but I'm still hindered by my lack of understanding. If anyone could explain how to find a and b or why it's impossible it would put my mind at ease.

Comment: Can I ask you your level of studies ?

Comment: @JeanMarie A sophmore in pre-calc with a bit too much passion for math

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For example, note that $9^3 = 3^6 = 27^2$ is possible. Actually, for $x, y\in\mathbb{N}$, there exist $a, b\in\mathbb{N}$ with $\gcd(a, b) = 1$ s.t $x^a=y^b$ if and only if there is $z\in\mathbb{N}$ s.t $x=z^b, y=z^a$. In this case the equation reduces to $z^{ab}=z^{ba}$, which is trivial.

This can be proved by prime factorization. Disregarding the trivial case $x=1$ or $y=1$, we can factorize $x, y$ as $$x = p_1^{k_1}p_2^{k_2}\cdots p_r^{k_r},\ \ \ \ \ y = q_1^{e_1}q_2^{e_2}\cdots q_s^{e_s}$$ where $p_i$'s are distinct primes and the same for $q_j$'s. Then the equation leads to $$p_1^{ak_1}p_2^{ak_2}\cdots p_r^{ak_r}=q_1^{be_1}q_2^{be_2}\cdots q_s^{be_s}$$ so that the uniqueness of prime factorization forces that $r=s$, each $p_i = q_j$ for some $j$, and $ak_i = be_j$. Then $a\mid e_j$ and $b\mid k_i$. Thus $$z = p_1^{k_1/b}p_2^{k_2/b}\cdots p_r^{k_r/b} = q_1^{e_1/a}q_2^{e_2/a}\cdots q_s^{e_s/a}$$ works.

Comment: This is a thorough, rigorously proved answer, but, as the OP mentioned that their math vocab isn't that strong, it might help to translate your first paragraph into "It can only happen when $x$ and $y$ are whole number powers of some other whole number".

Comment: I actually enjoyed this answer a lot because I didn't completely understand it at first but it lead me in the right direction of what I should be looking up. When I came back to it a few minutes later having looked at the other answer and some stuff online everything fell in place. Thank you!

Comment: Sorry for complicated phrasing. In addition, if $\gcd(a, b)>1$, things like this can happen: $4^6=8^4$ but $4$ is not a fourth power of any integer and $8$ is not a sixth powr of any integer. If we reduce the equation to $4^3 = 8^2$ then $4$ is a square of $2$, and $8$ is a cube of $2$.

Answer (score 1):

For example, $ 8^2 = 4^3 $ despite the fact that $8$ and $4$ are not powers of one another.

Let $\{p_i\}$ be the set that covers all prime factors of $x$ and $y$.

Let $\prod p_i^{g_i}$ be the prime factorization of $x$

Let $\prod p_i^{h_i}$ be the prime factorization of $y$

If $x^a = y^b$, we have $ \forall i, \hspace{5pt} h_i/g_i = a/b $

That is, the ratio of powers of prime factors must be a positive rational constant.